# docker-compose.yml error while trying to persist data on a volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

In my Docker Instance, I created a volume called `jokes`. I'm trying to build out my service now with `docker-compose up` but I keep getting this error message:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.db.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be an array
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: puma
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "postgres://postgres@db"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - "./:/app"
    working_dir: /app
  db:
    image: "postgres:10.3-alpine"
    volumes: "-jokes: /var/lib/postgresql/data"
volumes:
  jokes: ~
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

> How should I fix this?

As detailed in [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) you are required to give a list there (hence complaint about list), so move hyphen outside the quotes like so:

```
volumes: 
  - "jokes:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```